# Get list of circles of a user using Google Plus API using python client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I am using Google OAuth2 authentication with the following scope included:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

This allows my application to access a user's Google plus account information (basic).

Is it possbile to get a list of the user's **"Circles"** using the `google-api-python-client`
If yes, how?

**Note**: I am not using the Google+ Domains API, but the Google Plus API v1

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to do this with the regular Google+ API. As you seem to be aware, it can be achieved with the Google+ Domains API but that requires your target user to be a Google Apps account and you to have admin access to the domain.